# Dismissing pickers and keyboards invoked by a UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I am implementing an in-app browser using UIWebView, that shows an 'action' button up-top that - when tapped - scales the UIWebView and allows the user to perform some other actions.

If, however, at the point of tapping this 'action' button, the user were entering some text on the webview, or using a picker to select an option from a drop-down list, then the webview gets scaled without dismissing the keyboard/picker. Apart from being ugly, this also obscures my main view and controls.

So is there a way to make a UIWebView dismiss all associated input controls, such as keyboards/pickers, when asked to?

I tried using [myWebView resignFirstResponder] but that didn't work. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to do this by using
[myWebView endEditing:YES]

Comment: It worked! Thanks. I couldn't find this in the documentation for UIWebView though, where did you get this?

Comment: Note that this won't work if you're presenting a modal view on iPad with presentation style `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`. iOS intentionally keeps the keyboard on screen to prevent frequent in-and-out animations. (https://devforums.apple.com/message/166801#166801)